# Logo sides smoothen

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm about to create an intro video with a 3d font in center of the image.
Using Blender 2.8 and a svg graphic i started.. I extruded the whole graphic and now i see that the sides of the graphic are looking rough and unpolished.

Now i wanted to smoothen them but it always smoothes the whole graphic including the facing forward side wich is directly looking into the camera and the backside aswell..

How can i just smoothen the sides of the Logo without the face and back of the 3d object? [image: how the sides look]

and, additional one object is unable to smoothen

[image: Render result]

[image: Object can't be smoothened..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use *Smooth Shading* and *Auto-Smooth Normals* here.

To enable Smooth Shading, select the object, right-click, and select *Shade Smooth* near the top.

Smooth shading essentially takes the normals and averages them out, giving you a smooth look. However, you don't want that to happen on *every* edge. That results in hard edges being given a weird impossible shading (shown below).

[image]

To fix this issue, go to *Object Data Properties* > *Normals*  and enable *Auto-Smooth*. Changing the *Auto-smooth* angle will cause all the edges with faces at an angle less than or equal to the auto-smooth angle to be smoothed out. For example, if you set the angle to 90 degrees, You'll end up with the smooth shaded cylinder shown in the first image, as the angle between the vertical faces and the top face, is equal to 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: There's one issue i just discoverd, first is that i can't apply it to a certain object but it also looks different than the one's in my example i just sent.. It looks transparent even in object mode.. DId i make a mistake while editing it and can i revert it? I Posted a picture of the object right above in the original post

Comment: @JonathanAlexander That looks like you've entered wireframe viewport shading. You can toggle wireframe mode by pressing shift+z, or you can also hold down Z and select on the radial menu that pops up